# Use environment variables inside google-repo manifest?

Tags: manifest, repo

We are trying to start using google-repo in our project as the project is divided into multiple repositories. The problem is that our git server requires that one puts the username into the URL, e.g.

```
git clone ssh://username@git.server.com
```

But is it possible to get that into the manifest? I've tried the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
 <remote name="gerrit"
         fetch="ssh://$USER@git.server.com"
         review="ssh://$USER@git.server.com"
         revision="refs/heads/master"/>
 <default remote="gerrit" sync-j="4"/>
 <project name="project" remote="gerrit" path="project"/>
</manifest>
```

but google-repo simply uses `ssh://$USER@git.server.com` when cloning (that is, it does not dereference environment variable `$USER`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ssh config issue, you should not add $USER in the remote of your manifest.

In `~/.ssh/config`, add:

```
host whatever git.server.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    User <your_user>
```

IdentityFile should link to your ssh private key (YMMV).

You should now be able to

```
git clone ssh://git.server.com
```